# powershell: check for users that are logged in before deleting temp files

Tags: powershell

I'm relatively new to scripting, below is the script I'm using to clean temporary files over a day old, but I want to build in a check that will not delete an active (logged in) user's temp files and notify which objects were skipped.

```
#>
$oldTime = [int]1 # 1 day 
# Create array containing all user profile folders
$colProfiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Documents and Settings\" -Name
# Remove the "All Users" profile from the array
$colProfiles = $colProfiles -ne "All Users"

# Removes temporary files from each user profile folder
ForEach ( $objProfile in $colProfiles ) {
    # Remove all files and folders in user's Temp folder
    Get-ChildItem "C:\Documents and Settings\$objProfile\Local Settings\Temp\*" -recurse | WHERE {($_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-$oldTime))} | remove-item -force -recurse
    # Remove all files and folders in user's Temporary Internet Files. The -force switch on Get-ChildItem gets hidden directories as well.
    Get-ChildItem "C:\Documents and Settings\$objProfile\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*" -recurse -force | WHERE {($_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-$oldTime))} | remove-item -force -recurse
```

Comment: http://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/01/quick-hit-find-currently-logged-on-users/ possibly relevant

Answer (score 0):

you can test username before deleting files:

```
if ($objProfile -neq ( gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem ).username.split('\')[1]))
{ .. can delete ..}
```

or

```
if ($objProfile -neq [environment]::UserName)
    { .. can delete ..}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian I'll give that a try.